# Laravel 5 infinite Scroll + Paginate

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination, infinite-scroll

For do infinite scroll with paginate in l5 i found a lot of articles but they all use this paginate() function as they use result set from db but i'm fetching the data from googlefontapi as json so when i use paginate() in json it cause an error and also in array. my code

```
public function index(){


    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=!";
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents( $url ))->paginate(10);
    $font_list = "";
    foreach ( $result->items as $font )
    {
        $font_list[] = [
            'font_name' => $font->family,
            'category' => $font->category,
            'variants' => implode(', ', $font->variants),
            // subsets
            // version
            // files
        ];
    }

    return view('website_settings')->with('data', $font_list);

}
```

and the error is

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::paginate()
```

is there any other way to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you need to use a `Illluminate\Support\Collection`. Then we can pass the `Illuminate\Support\Collection` to an instance of the `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` class to get our `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` instance back. Make sure to `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

Then, create a collection from your results:

```
$collection = collect(json_decode($file_get_contents($url), true));
```

Finally, construct the paginator.

```
$paginator = new Paginator($collection, $per_page, $current_page);
```

Or one line it because that's how you roll:

```
$paginator = new Paginator(collect(json_decode($file_get_contents($url), true)));
```

You can also cache the collection if you need it and only reload it if the request is not an XHR request, such as during the page load. This is useful when you need to keep `API` requests to a minimum, and will also generally help speed up the performance of the request, as any HTTP request will have latency associated with it.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: No luck bro it says Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\collection()@Ohgodwhy

Comment: @Ranjith Sorry, my own typo. That should be `collect` not `collection`.