# How to create custom pagination on API returned results in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I know how to create pagination from database returned records in laravel view, but need to create the same from API returned results.

I have an api which have 500 000 records. but it only returns maximum 500 records at a time. I can set the value to a lower than 500 but not more than that in a single api call. I have total records returned by the api also.

I want to create a pagination of 50 results per page. Can anyone provide the code for this in laravel 5.2 using blade template or jquery.

Api Call returns:

Total results found - 456 789

Total records returned - 500 or less

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [metaData] => Array
                (
                    [resultsAvailable] => 228246
                    [resultsReturned] => 500
                    [firstResult] => 1
                    [lastResult] => 500

                    )                

        [results] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 100000
                        [1] => 1
                        [2] => 14327
                        [3] => 5
                        [4] => 3
                        [5] => 2014-02-18T07:40:23.000Z
                        [6] => 4
                        [7] => 390770731738-385691128026
                        [8] => 1
                        [9] => 2014-02-20T20:51:56.000Z
                        [10] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 100001
                        [1] => 1
                        [2] => 14328
                        [3] => 5
                        [4] => 3
                        [5] => 2014-02-18T08:20:56.000Z
                        [6] => 4
                        [7] => 026-2336690-3199543
                        [8] => 1
                        [9] => 2014-02-20T20:51:55.000Z
                        [10] => 0
                    )
.......



                [499] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 100511
                        [1] => 1
                        [2] => 14688
                        [3] => 5
                        [4] => 3
                        [5] => 2014-02-20T19:35:00.000Z
                        [6] => 4
                        [7] => 205-0866154-3716348
                        [8] => 1
                        [9] => 2014-02-20T20:46:45.000Z
                        [10] => 0
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: Please provide your code. The Controller and the corresponding View would be a good start.

Comment: [SEe my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37960470/1206267) which explains in detail how to paginate any array.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy not what i am looking for.

Comment: @LaravelUser Can you explain why that's not what you're looking for? it gives you the ability to paginate anything. What am I missing?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i dont have all results to make a collection at a time. api only return 500 or less results on single call.

Comment: You can hook into the paginator class and when it's over get the next results if the total page count * your limit is less then the total count. that's just standard stuff..

Comment: no i don't want to call the api multiple times over and over

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add use:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;
```

and now you can use:

```
$paginator = new Paginator($items, $count, $limit, $page, [
            'path'  => $this->request->url(),
            'query' => $this->request->query(),
        ]);
```

to get data in the same format as paginating on model object;

Comment: i have to modify this to my use but i get the idea of LengthAwarePaginator

Comment: I also uses the same. But I am getting only partial URL which is like `/page=2`. I was getting the complete URL when using paginate(). Also I am not getting previous URL.

Comment: What are you sending as $items? Does it have only 500 records?